# Node.js Spawn Display STDOUT live not working

Tags: node.js, spawn

I have an app it receives file links and downloads them, for downloading I am used aria2c.

For doing this first I used `exec`, but since I want to get download progress then I used `spawn`

Here is code i am using for download file with aria2c:

```
'use strict';

const
    spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawn,
    aria2c = spawn( 'aria2c', ['-x8', 'https://wa-us-ping.vultr.com/vultr.com.100MB.bin' ] );

aria2c.stdout.on( 'data', data => {
    console.log( `stdout: ${data}` );
});

aria2c.stderr.on( 'data', data => {
    console.log( `stderr: ${data}` );
});

aria2c.on( 'close', code => {
    console.log( `child process exited with code ${code}` );
});
```

When I run this code it doesn't print aria2c output to stdout, it only shows it when download finished.

I want to know how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `aria2c` very well, but this is what I came up with:

```
// enable a specific log level
aria2c = spawn( 'aria2c', ['--log-level=info', '-l-', '-x8', 'https://wa-us-ping.vultr.com/vultr.com.100MB.bin' ]);

// find the percentage (this is not well-tested...)
aria2c.stdout.on( 'data', data => {
  data = data.toString();
  if (/ETA:/.test(data)) {
    let pct = data.match(/\(.*?%\)/)[0];
    console.log( `stdout: ${ pct }` );
  }
});
```

(the rest of the code remains the same)

The reason you can't (easily) capture the default output is because the progress lines are ended with just a carriage return, not a newline, which causes those lines to be buffered and you'll end up with one `data` event at the end that contains *all* those lines.

By changing the loglevel, the progress lines are interspersed with other lines, which will either make the buffer fill up quicker, or cause more I/O flushes so the `data` event is triggered more often, allowing you to capture the progress data.

Answer (score 0):

--summary-interval=SEC

Set interval in seconds to output download progress summary.

Setting 0 suppresses the output. Default: 60

https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-summary-interval